# Error jQuery y Ajax, me devuelve [object Object] de una consulta SQL

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, prepared-statements

Tengo un error, y el PHP no me devuelve bien la consulta `sql`.

Esto es lo que realizo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editarCliente', function () {

var idc = $(this).attr("id");
console.log(idc);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/editar_cliente.php',
    data: {'idc': idc}
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    console.log(listas_rep);
    $('#editarCliente').show();
    $('#resultEditCliente').html(listas_rep);
  })
  .fail(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    alert(err);
  })

});
```

Me saca bien la `id`, (comprobado por consola)

Ahora, este es el `php`:

```
<?php  

require_once 'php/conexion.php';

    $idcliente = $_POST['idc'];

    $mysqli = getConn();

if (isset($idcliente)) {
    function editarCliente() {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente = ?";

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $idcliente);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
        $resultado = $stmt->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $stmt->close();
       // $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        $ec = '<form id="form_edit_cliente" method="POST">
                <table id="table" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">';

        for ($i=0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) { 
        //while($resultado[$i] = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $ec .= '<h2>Editar cliente #'.$resultado[$i]["id_cliente"].'</h2>
                    <h3>Datos Personales</h3>

                    <input id="idc" type="hidden" value="'.$resultado[$i]["id_cliente"].'">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="campoP">Nombre</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="nombre" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["nombre"].'"></td>
                            <td class="td barcode" style="text-align:center" colspan="6" resultado[$i]span="2"></td>
                            <td class="campoP">Fecha Registro:</td>
                            <td class="td">' .$resultado[$i]["fecha_registro"]. '</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="campoP">Apellidos</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="apellidos" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["apellidos"].'"></td>
                            <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                            <td class="td"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="campoP">Telefono</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="telefono" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["telefono"].'"></td>
                            <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                            <td class="td"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="campoP">Email</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="email" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["email"].'"></td>
                            <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                            <td class="td"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <h3>Datos Comerciales</h3>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Comercial</td>
                            <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="ncomercial" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["ncomercial"].'"></td>
                            <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                            <td class="campoP" style="width: 10%">Nombre Fiscal</td>
                            <td class="td" style="width: 25%"><input id="nfiscal" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["nfiscal"].'"></td>
                            <td class="campoP">NIF/CIF</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="cif" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["cif"].'"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="campoP">Direccion</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="direccion" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["direccion"].'"></td>
                            <td class="td" colspan="5"></td>
                            <td class="campoP">Ciudad</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="ciudad" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["ciudad"].'"></td>
                            <td class="campoP">CP</td>
                            <td class="td"><input id="cp" type="text" value="'.$resultado[$i]["cp"].'"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>';

        }

        $ec .= '</table>
                <br><br>
                <center><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Editar Cliente"></center>
                </form>';

        return $ec;
    }
} else {
    $ec .= "No existe la variable id cliente";
}
echo editarCliente();
?>
```

No me muestra ni si quiera que `"No existe la variable id cliente"`

Me devuelve en el alert `[object Object]`

Y por consola:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8888/seoagency/php/editar_cliente.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

No le veo ninguna lógica de que esto no funcione :/

Agradezco que puedan ayudarme a solventarlo, gracias.

Comment: Si mal no estoy, esto $resultado = $stmt->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC); debería ser: $resultado = $resultado->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC); por que en la linea de arriba obtienes los resultados con: $resultado = $stmt->get_result();

Comment: El error 500 indica que hay algo mal en el servidor (en tu código PHP). Si revisas el log de errores verás lo que está mal. Por ejemplo `get_result` no funcionará si no tienes instalado el driver `mysqlnd` en tu servidor. Si no sabes como revisar el log de errores, puedes depurar tus variables, por ejemplo: `var_dump($resultado);` , si te arroja `NULL` o un array vacío puede ser un indicador de que no tienes `mysqlnd`.

Answer (score 0):

No te responde el **"No existe la variable id cliente"** porque debes de hacerle un return a la variable **$ec** en ese else

** Me devuelve esto**

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (a)
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ (a)
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (a)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
""
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (a,b)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
500
statusCode
:
ƒ (a)
statusText
:
"Internal Server Error"
then
:
ƒ (b,d,e)
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: Cierto, justo acababa de corregirlo, aun así, no funciona

Comment: Pero te sale aun el erro 500?

Comment: Si, el error continúa

Comment: Ok en la consola donde te dice error 500 dale un click y deberia de decirte lo que estas enviando y la respuesta, estas usando firefox?

Comment: Utilizo Chrome, he editado tu respuesta, para que veas lo que me saca en consola, no llego a ninguna conclusión

Comment: En vez de darle a la consola dale a la pestaña network o red y alli le das click a la peticion y si deberia de salir un preview o previa donde te sale lo que estas mandando y un response o respuesta que es donde esta el error, avisame

Comment: Me dice que el error está en el archivo editar_clientes.php con error 500, no me saca nada más

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83285/discussion-between-david-leonardo-molina-ruiz-dav-and-javier-avila-fernandez).